# Powerbank and Lithium-ion charging/discharging module stop working under a current supplied to the load

Tags: lithium-ion, protection, discharging

I have made some tests with a [HX160S3 26800mAh power bank](https://www.amazon.co.uk/HETP-Power-Bank-Charger%E3%80%90Quick-Delivery%E3%80%91/dp/B08F25Y7X5) and a [134N3P charging/discharging/protection/DC/DCconverter module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002619314989.html?src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=248-630-5778&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&aff_platform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&isSmbAutoCall=false&needSmbHouyi=false&albcp=10191220526&albag=107473525328&trgt=539263010115&crea=fr1005002619314989&netw=u&device=c&albpg=539263010115&albpd=fr1005002619314989&gclid=CjwKCAjwz_WGBhA1EiwAUAxIcU6poXck5z7qyIDsnHTi_dThSc2nP3GwFJPQ7_ChY-ltWDLvTUJlqhoCYAsQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and I have made kind of the same observation: when they are in discharging mode (supplying power to a load), they stop working after a while for a load drawing small current (I saw that the limit is about 100 mA). So, it seems they must have a minimum load current to work properly.

For the power bank, after like 10 min, it stops working and I need to unplug and replug.
For the module, every 10 seconds, it stop working for 30 ms then restarts working until the next cut off.

Does someone know why?

(Additional question: does someone know how to reduce this limit of load current?)

Thank you in advance,

Comment: That's how these things were designed. It'll be in the manual/datasheet of your devices that they have a low-current cutoff. Amazon and aliexpress are known for facilitating the sale of devices with insufficient documentation, so there's nothing to answer here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok but not helping at all to bring piece of answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is done on purpose so they turn off automatically to save power and to not damage the internal battery so it does not go fully empty. Basically they turn off when there is not enough load on it, like when a mobile phone stops taking current when it is full.

Comment: OK, as Justme mentionned it above, it is to not get the battery cell fully empty because of the DC/DC sink current. For one who are interested in, I ve found a [good link](https://www.audiosciencereview.com/forum/index.php?threads/powerbank-keep-alive-to-power-low-current-5v-devices.4065/) explaining this